# Eclipse : switch workspace from svn to git (code already migrated)

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, eclipse-mars

I have a workspace that points to an SVN repository(Eclipse Mars).
The code under this repository has been migrated to git.
How can I point to this new git repository without breaking my current workspace?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:

- Close eclipse.
- Save the whole directory on a zip, just in case.
- Save all your local change from the revisión you are working on. What I would call *stash your changes* in git terms
- inside the directory of the project, run : `git init .`
- Set a remote to the svn clone you made on git
- run `git fetch --all`
- Find on git the exact same revision you are working on svn
- Run `git checkout --force the-revision-id`

At this point, you could delete .svn because you are already switched to git. When starting eclipse, it should just show stuff as if you are working on git, no svn.